# Best site/software to visualize Most Active Open Source Projects?

Tags: open-source, data-visualization

As a Microsoft .NET developer I have noticed a marked increase in the number of new Open Source frameworks and software tools that directly impact how your design a software solution. So much so that if you don't happen to be talking to the right person at the right time you may miss a whole major development. I started to wonder if there is anyone out there who is tracking and charting the "most active open source projects" over time. *To be able to visualize what are the up and coming and most active open source projects appearing in any given space/category (e.g c#/web development space) would be incredibly useful*. Searching around on the web I have only managed to find visualizations of specific projects (e.g. code_swarm and Gource) but nothing tracking Open Source projects over-all.

Do you know of any such sites?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ohloh.net/ is such a website - provides description, summaries and categorization for many open source projects; shows info about commit activities and lots of other useful info.

for an example check this out - http://www.ohloh.net/p/jQuery/analyses/latest

Hope this helps :o)